# Is calling ssh without user is same as calling it with getuser?

Tags: python, ssh, getpass

If I want to start a ssh process from python, is invoking `ssh` without any user (`subprocess.run(['ssh', 'remotehost'])`), is equivalent to invoking `ssh` with getuser (`subprocess.run(['ssh', '{}@remotehost'.format(getpass.getuser())])`) ?

If not, is there a reliable way to get what would have been the default user to ssh otherwise?

What I am trying to do is, start a long running process in the background in remotehost. Then I want to store the pid of the newly created process along with the user. But I am unsure how to get the user in case the user passes user=None to my function (which is technically correct as ssh doesn't necessarily require user argument).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to extract the user specified in the SSH config for this host?

Comment: @wRAR Edited question adding what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ssh uses your current username if you don't specify one explicitly. I guess that means, "yes"?

Comment: @larsks no, it can use a different one if it's specified oin the config

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB so do you want to save the remote user name that was used to connect?

Comment: @wrar That would be "specifying one explicitly".

Comment: @wRAR yes, if user provides None to my function, I want to store the actual user to which the ssh connection was established

Comment: @larsks no, as the question was about not specifying it on the command line

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I don't think you can get that programmatically after calling `ssh(1)`

Comment: @wRAR Now, whenever I use ssh without user argument, it takes my logged in user name (the one that appears in $HOME). In which scenario can this differ?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I've mentioned that twice already but it can differ when you specify a different user in `.ssh/config`

Comment: @wRAR Thanks. Also, if I login to a machine as user1, will my working directory be always `/home/user1` or can differ? If it differs, it is controlled by which variable / config?

Comment: It will be the home directory of that user.